# fieldset breaks phone numbers on mobile

Tags: html, mobile, fieldset

On mobile devices (ios & android), if there is a phone number in a fieldset tag, the phone number is no longer clickable.

```
<fieldset>
    <div>(800) 555-5555 - does not work on mobile</div>
</fieldset>
<div>(800) 555-5555 - works on mobile</div>
```

Does anyone have a solution? (besides not using fieldset)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Fieldset is used in a form to group elements.
If you only look for a style, use a div with CSS formating.